# JavaScript: splitting letters followed by digits

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I want to split a string contains letters followed by digits, the separator should be the next letter.

'C3B1A60' ===> ['C3', 'B1', 'A60']

I've tried to use SPLIT with RegEx and it worked fine except it produces empty string in between:

```
var splits = 'C3B1A60'.split(/([A-Z]\d+)/);
// [ '', 'C3', '', 'B1', '', 'A60', '' ]
```

I know I can workaround to remove them, but is there a straightforward way of doing it?!

Comment: Use `'C3B1A60'.match(/[A-Z]\d+/g)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works perfectly, I don't know how I missed that, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.filter(Boolean)` in order to keep only desired items.

```js
var str = 'C3B1A60';
var splits = 'C3B1A60'.split(/([A-Z]\d+)/).filter(Boolean);
console.log(splits);
```